# Query an SQLite DB synchronously in C

Tags: c, sqlite

I am trying to use SQLite in C.

The interface I know exists for querying,

```
sqlite3_exec
```

Allows querying data only asynchronously (as far as I found in my searches).

Is there any way to get a result to a "Select count(*) ..." from an SQLite DB synchronously without having to implement something that waits for the data, and returns it to the same function?

I practically want to implement a "howManyItems" method that returns the actual result to its caller...

Thanks.

Comment: All SQLite querying functions execute synchronously. Are you sure you are using the official C API and not some wrapper?

Comment: I am actually not sure if the run itself is synchronous or asynchronously - but the results are definitely being returned in a callback manner (I will try the suggested solution tomorrow probably) which is out of the scope of the caller, and not how I want to get the results...

Comment: Ah, `sqlite3_exec` takes a callback that is called with each row. Yes, the `sqlite3_prepare` functions are what you want.

Comment: Thanks.. by the way - is it being run synchronously? just for knowing if my guess was right or wrong..

Comment: Yes, it runs in the same thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming an open `sqlite3 *db`, use [`sqlite3_prepare_v2()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) and [`sqlite3_step()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) (ignoring error checking for brevity):

```c
sqlite3_stmt *statement = null;

// prepare our query
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "select count(*) from foo;", -1, &statement, 0);

// if there were parameters to bind, we'd do that here

// retrieve the first row (only row, in this case) of the results
int result = sqlite3_step(statement);

if (result == SQLITE_ROW)
{
  // retrieve the value of the first column (0-based)
  int count = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);

  // do something with count
}

// free our statement
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```