# How do I get data from an sqlite table in C?

Tags: c, sqlite, codeblocks

I'm trying to create a database using C. I created a table called newCell, and inserted some values into it. Now, I want to iterate through all the rows and get values from 3 of the 6 columns per row. I've been trying to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637701/sqlite-c-interface-get-single-value-result), and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941088/query-an-sqlite-db-synchronously-in-c). It inserts the values into the table, but it does not seem to print them out. I expected to insert values into the table, then iterate through them and print the xCell, yCell, and zCell columns. Below is my code:

```
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
int main()
{

char* err;
sqlite3* db;
sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
sqlite3_open("DB_test.db", &db);
double result;
double x,y,z;
char table[]= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newCell\
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\
    xCell REAL NOT NULL,\
    yCell REAL,\
    zCell REAL,\
    volume REAL,\
    count INTEGER DEFAULT 1,\
    CONSTRAINT name_unique UNIQUE (xCell,yCell,zCell)\
    );";
int rc = sqlite3_exec(db,table, NULL, NULL,&err);

if(rc != SQLITE_OK){
    printf("error1: %s\n", err);
}
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    char query[]= "INSERT INTO newCell(xCell,yCell,zCell,volume,count)\
            VALUES(3.8,6.3,4.22,2.112,1)\
            ON CONFLICT(xCell,yCell,zCell) DO UPDATE SET count=count+1";

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db,query,NULL,NULL,&err);
    if(rc != SQLITE_OK){
        printf("error2: %s\n", err);
    }

}

double ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,"SELECT xCell,yCell,zCell FROM 
newCell", -1,&stmt,0);
if(ret){
    printf("error3: %g\n",ret);
}
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    sqlite3_step(stmt);

    if(ret == SQLITE_ROW){
        x = sqlite3_column_double(stmt,0);
        y = sqlite3_column_double(stmt,1);
        z = sqlite3_column_double(stmt,2);

        printf("%g %g %g",x,y,z);

    } else if(ret == SQLITE_DONE){
        printf("Identifier");
        break;
    } else{
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        printf("some error encountered\n");
        break;
    }
}

sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
sqlite3_close(db);



return 0;
}`
```

I followed [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637701/sqlite-c-interface-get-single-value-result), but did not get the result that I expected. I expected to insert values into the table, then iterate through them and print the xCell, yCell, and zCell columns.

Comment: Your table doesn't have columns named x, y or z.

Comment: `printf("error3: %s\n",ret);` `ret` is an int but you're telling `printf()` to expect a string. That's not going to work well. Neither is continuing on after an error... just printing a message isn't enough.

Comment: I fixed the ret value from 
ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,"SELECT x,y,z FROM newCell", -1,&stmt,0); TO
ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,"SELECT xCell,yCell,zCell FROM newCell", -1,&stmt,0);, and I also changed the datatype of ret to double, and it's still not working. It says "Some error encountered". Any ideas why this was? Also, can you expound on "Just printing a message isn't enough"? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ret` is not getting updated during stepping, it still holds the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`.

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    sqlite3_step(stmt);

    if(ret == SQLITE_ROW){
```

Capture return value of `sqlite3_step` as below.

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    ret = sqlite3_step(stmt);

    if(ret == SQLITE_ROW){
```